# How to sum input fields row and column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have searched a lot and couldn't find a solution, and since my code abilities are somewhat limited, I ask for help.

What I am trying to do is exactly what is found here: http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/335/

```
$(function(){
    var $iTableTotals = $("#iTable .colTotal");
    var $eTableTotals = $("#eTable .colTotal");
    var $diffValues = $(".diffValue");
    $(".colTotal").on('change keyup', function() {
        $iTableTotals.each(function(i){
            var diff = Number($iTableTotals.eq(i).val()) - Number($eTableTotals.eq(i).val());
            $diffValues.eq(i).val(diff);
        });
    });
    $iTableTotals.eq(0).change();
});
```

But I would like to have input fields instead of pre-loaded numbers.
To clarify, I found this code on the web, I am no the author of this code.

Thank you.

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: Please clarify: so you want cells in the rows labeled "Row1", "Row2", and "Row3" (except for the "Total By Row" cells) to be input boxes instead of static numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly 100% sure what you meant by having input fields instead of pre-loaded numbers. Please see forked Fiddle, hope that's what you meant:
http://jsfiddle.net/B9EWd/

HTML:

```
<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <td></td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>Watermelon</td>
            <td>Strawberry</td>
            <td>Total By Row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Row1</td>
            <td class="rowAA"><input value="7" /></td>
            <td class="rowAA"><input value="2" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB"><input value="3" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB"><input value="4" /></td>
            <td class="totalRow"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Row2</td>
            <td class="rowAA"><input value="1" /></td>
            <td class="rowAA"><input value="2" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB"><input value="3" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB"><input value="4" /></td>
            <td class="totalRow"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row3</td>
            <td class="rowAA"><input value="1" /></td>
            <td class="rowAA"><input value="5" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB"><input value="3" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB"><input value="4" /></td>
            <td class="totalRow"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function updateTotals() {
    $("#sum_table tr:not(:first,:last)  td:last-child").text(function(){
        var t = 0;
        $(this).prevAll().find("input").each(function(){ 
            t += parseInt( $(this).val(), 10 ) || 0;
        });
        return t;
    });

    $("#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").text(function(i){
        var t = 0;
        $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i + 2)+") input").each(function(){
            t += parseInt( $(this).val(), 10 ) || 0;
        });
        return "Total: " + t;
    });
}

$( "input" ).change( updateTotals );
updateTotals();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I meant, thank you. It would be even better to have a sum of the totals in the last position of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            getTotal();

            $(".txtNumber").change(function () {
                getTotal();
            });
        });

        function getTotal() {
            $("#sum_table tr:not(:first,:last)  td:last-child").text(function () {
                var t = 0;
                $(this).prevAll().each(function () {
                    t += parseInt($(this).find('input').val(), 10) || 0;
                });
                return t;
            });

            $("#sum_table tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").text(function (i) {
                var t = 0;
                $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child(" + (i + 2) + ")").each(function () {
                    t += parseInt($(this).find('input').val(), 10) || 0;
                });
                return "Total: " + t;
            });
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <td></td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Orange</td>
            <td>Watermelon</td>
            <td>Strawberry</td>
            <td>Total By Row</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row1</td>
            <td class="rowAA">
                <input type="text" value="1" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="rowAA">
                <input type="text" value="2" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB">
                <input type="text" value="3" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB">
                <input type="text" value="4" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="totalRow"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row2</td>
            <td class="rowAA">
                <input type="text" value="1" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="rowAA">
                <input type="text" value="2" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB">
                <input type="text" value="3" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB">
                <input type="text" value="4" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="totalRow"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row3</td>
            <td class="rowAA">
                <input type="text" value="1" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="rowAA">
                <input type="text" value="5" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB">
                <input type="text" value="3" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="rowBB">
                <input type="text" value="4" class="txtNumber" /></td>
            <td class="totalRow"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
            <td class="totalCol"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant. It would also be great to have a sum of the totals in the last position of the table.